# How to get a dynamic type hint at "code-writing level" with enum condition

Tags: python, python-typing

I am trying to build a python 3.7 package with API manager class that provides an access to some different classes which have their own inner methods, fields, etc.

I want to provide easy access via one class, that allows to invoke a method, which returns a proper class depending on provided enum parameter which maps each class. Additionally, I want built-in IDE linter (intellisence, code autocomplete, etc.) to understand actual type of returned class instance, that allows to navigate around its methods and other stuff.

Below is a example of my implementation:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


class APIClientA:

    def client_a_method(self):
        print('client a: method executed')


class APIClientB:

    def client_b_method1(self):
        print('client b: method 1 executed')

    def client_b_method2(self):
        print('client b: method 2 executed')


class APIType(Enum):
    A = APIClientA
    B = APIClientB

class APIManager:

    @property
    def clients(self) -> Type[APIType]:
        return APIType

    def get_api_by_type(self, api_client_cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        return api_client_cls()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mgr = APIManager()

    api_a = mgr.get_api_by_type(mgr.clients.A.value)
    api_b = mgr.get_api_by_type(mgr.clients.B.value)
```

And it works, at least at VS Code IDE with installed PyLance extension:

[image]
[image]

But I didn't like the fact, that one who want to use my library should pass not enum values (i.e. `mgr.clients.A`), which is intuitive, but its values instead (i.e. `mgr.clients.B.value`). I tried to refactor it passing invocation of value property inside `get_api_by_type` method, but I haven't got success in it.

Maybe overall approach is bad and there is some other solution?

Comment: Does VSCode not work with simple inheritance? `class BaseClient: pass; class APITypeA(BaseClient): ...; class APITypeB(BaseClient): ...`?

Comment: Of course it does, but it implies to specify each API class individually at the code, which is not so succinct if we talking about tens of different APIs, Idea was to provide a factory method with type matching for IDE's linter

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are referring to, but `A.__subclasses__()` will return all direct subclasses of `A` without you needing to enumerate them explicitly with `APIType`.

Comment: That can be used to create a mapping of subclass names to subclasses: `{c.__name__: c for c in A.__subclasses__()}`. This would appear to cover all runtime uses of `APIManager`; I just don't know if it works with VS Code's discovery code.

Comment: Maybe I understand you wrong, but it seems that `__subclasses__` will work only at a runtime, I am talking about "design-time" when you are writing a code at IDE and it is needed to refer to a particular class just with type hinting

Comment: Ah, good point. `__subclass__` is a method that returns information (some of which is *available* statically) but may not be useable statically.